# Reducing a fraction containing numbers in numerical form

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

I am looking for a function that would transform a fraction of the form:

$$\frac{1.0\times 10^{-10}}{1.0\times 10^{-11}+1.0\times 10^{-12}\,x}$$

into this:
$$\frac{1.0}{1.0\times 10^{-1}+1.0\times 10^{-2}\,x}$$

or this:
$$\frac{100.0}{10.0+1.0\,x}\;.$$

I've tried `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` but they don't work this way.

Any help will be appreciated.

[edit]

Oh, when I tried `Simplify`, it was a harder case of something like

$$\frac{1.0\times 10^{-10}+1.0\times 10^{-12}\,x}{1.0\times 10^{-11}+1.0\times 10^{-12}\,x}$$

Actually, `Simplify` works for the previous fraction but does not simplify this one.

However, answer by Carl Woll (in the comments) works perfectly for both. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps `N @ Simplify @ Rationalize[expr, 0]`?

Comment: `Cancel` yields the desired result (last one).

Comment: With v12.2 on a Mac, just using `Simplify` produces the last result requested, `100./(10. + 1.*x)`

Comment: `((1.0*10^-10 + 1.0*10^-12*x)/(1.0*10^-11 + 1.0*10^-12*x) // Cancel) /. {1. -> 1}` works also.

Comment: @Somos Oh, yes, that's right. So, yarchik's answer is also valid. Thanks.

Comment: also `Factor@expr`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

```
(1.0 10^-10)/(1.0 10^-11 + 1.0 10^-12 x) // Together

(*100./(1. x + 10.)*)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this. Here are two that come first into mind.

```
expr = (1.0*10^-10)/(1.0*10^-11 + 1.0*10^-12*x);
```

1. 

```
1/Simplify[Denominator[expr]/Numerator[expr]]

(* 1/(0.1 + 0.01 x) *)
```

2. 

```
MapAt[Simplify[Divide[#, Numerator[expr]]] &, expr, {{1}, {2, 1}}]

(* 1./(0.1 + 0.01 x)  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

How about this. Dividing both the numerator and denominator by the prefactor of `x` .Works for both expressions.

```
expr = (1.0*10^-10)/(1.0*10^-11 + 1.0*10^-12*x)

fac = Cases[expr, Times[aa_, x] -> aa, \[Infinity]][[1]]; 
(Numerator[expr ]/fac // Simplify)/
(Denominator[expr]/fac // Simplify)

(*   100./(10. + 1. x)   *)

expr = (1.0*10^-10 + 1.0*10^-12*x)/(1.0*10^-11 + 1.0*10^-12*x
)
```

With more complicated expressions use `MantissaExponent`

```
expr = (1.0*10^-10 + 1.1*10^-12*x)/(1.0*10^-11 + 3.5*10^-12*x)

fac = Cases[expr, Times[aa_, x] -> aa, \[Infinity]][[1]];

(Numerator[expr]/10^Last@MantissaExponent[fac] // Simplify)/
(Denominator[expr]/10^Last@MantissaExponent[fac] // Simplify)

(*   (10. + 0.11 x)/(1. + 0.35 x)   *)
```